# Можно ли менять стили при смене размера окна?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть ли в bootstrap такой функционал, что можно прописать необходимый тебе класс для конкретного размера окна? К примеру `col-md-()`, где вместо скобок необходимый класс, а `col-sm-()` - уже другой класс? Или это надо делать через media или создавать 2 разных блока, один из которых скрывать при данном размере окна?

Comment: надо делать через media, либо через js

Comment: тут как бы зависит еще хотите ли вы изменить css-свойства или для вас важно именно добавлять-удалять класс. Css-свойства можно изменять через media в рамках одного класса. А вот если нужно обязательно добавить или удалить класс - это уже через js только.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, да. Я это знаю, просто стало интересно есть ли такая возможность на bootstrap. Спасибо

Comment: Ну многие свойства можно менять дефолтынми классами так как вы хотите. Например "pb-0 p-md-5" для того, чтобы padding был разным на разных разрешениях. Так что именно некоторыми свойствами управлять из бутстрапа на разных разрешениях таки можно.